# Why setFont Function Can't work correctly?

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts, awt

I tried to use setFont function of an AWT object, such as Label and Button. However, it only changed the style and size. The font family was still unchanged.

There is no solution on the Internet. All of the existing contents are about Swing JButton, not AWT Button.

Is there a way to make setFont function of AWT objects work?

I'm using the newest version of Eclipse on Windows 11. JDK version is 21.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Panel;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Frame frame = new Frame("ChangeButtonFont");

        Font font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 32);

        Button button1 = new Button("Comic Sans");
        button1.setFont(font);
        button1.setForeground(Color.blue);

        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.add(button1);

        frame.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
          }
        });
    }
}
```

[Code pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2BQs.png)

I use this demo to test, the problem still exists. If I replace "Button" with Swing object "JButton", the function will work with font family successfully changed.
[Button doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2ydp.png)
[JButton works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZhUP.png)

Comment: Why on earth are you using AWT components?. These are completely obsolete and acquiring skills using them will be completely useless for you

Comment: Do you get different results if you place all of your code in a Runnable, the pass that Runnable to [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))?  Most of your method calls are not allowed unless they occur in the AWT event dispatch thread.